# Xen and KVM belongs to which type of virutalizations(full or para)?

Tags: linux, kvm, xen

Always it's getting hard for me to figure out XEN and KVM which type of virtualization. Looking for a detailed answer so I can use it as reference every time.

Comment: Xen is paravirt (guest knows it's running in a VM and changes its behavior) . KVM is full virt (unmodified guest), although you can load paravirt drivers into your guest (e.g. virtio) to make it perform better.

Comment: Also Xen can run VMs in HVM mode which is fully virtualised just as KVM is (and you can load PV drivers to improve performance as well). Xen also has a 'PVH' mode which is somewhere between the two.